# qstring to qchar specialcharacter

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I am working on a parser. I want to parse a text file char by char.

```
bool parse(QString fileName,
           QString fieldTerminator,
           QString lineTerminator,
           QString encloseChar)
{
    QChar ft = *(fieldTerminator.unicode());
    QChar lt = *(lineTerminator.unicode());
    QChar ec = *(encloseChar.unicode());

    QFile file(fileName);

    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        qDebug() << file.errorString();
        return false;
    }

    QTextStream inStream(&file);

    while(!inStream.atEnd())
    {
        QChar c;
        inStream >> c;

        if(c == ft)
            qDebug() << "fieldterm";
        else if(c == lt)
            qDebug() << "lineterm";
        else if(c == ec)
            qDebug() << "encloseChar";
    }

    return true;
}
```

I'm having problems converting the `fieldTerminator` etc. to a special character (`QChar::SpecialCharacter`).

e.g: If I pass `fieldTerminator = "\n"` into the function, `ft = '\'` (92)

Is there an easy way to archive it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, when I pass in `QString( "\n" )` I get `lt = 10 '\n'`.

Comment: -__- interesting:
[screen](http://s16.postimg.org/59bln2k6d/Unbenannt.jpg)
why is it not working for me?

Comment: Because I misunderstood the question,see my answer.

Comment: Could you provide example of using that function? With `fieldTerminator = "\n"`. Or say what is size of `fieldTerminator` string (when you pass data like in screenshot)

Answer (score 1):

Parsing text quickly becomes a statefull affair. If you want to recognize the two character sequence `\` `n` as the newline character `\n`, then comparing a single character (`c == ft`) is not sufficient. You can remember the previous character and check both the current and the previous characters.

```
QString parse(QString const& text)
{
    static QChar BACKSLASH('\\');
    static QByteArray const SPECIAL_CHARS ("\"'?abfnrtv");
    static QString    const SPECIAL_QCHARS ("\\\"\'\?\a\b\f\n\r\t\v") ;

    QString result;
    QChar prev;

     for( int i = 0; i < text.size(); ++i)
     {
        QChar c = text[i];

        if( prev == BACKSLASH )
        {
            int idx = SPECIAL_CHARS.indexOf( c );
            if( idx != -1)
            {
                result.append( SPECIAL_QCHARS[idx] );
            }
            else
            {
               result.append( prev );
               result.append( c );
            }
            prev = 0;
        }
        else
        {
           result.append( c );
           prev = c;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: i think it doesn't work, because `inStream >> c;` gives you only one char e.g. `\n`

Comment: It does work because it remembers the previous char in `rev`. I fixed a typo in the assignment `prev = c`. So prev will be `'\'` and c will be `'n'` during the second iteration.

Comment: I rewrote the example to support multiple special characters.

Comment: rewrote example to build and return result.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting QString fieldTerminator = "\n" to be 1 char long and contain 'end of line'? It does not work that way: fieldTerminator would be two chars long: '\' and 'n'; if you want to follow printf() logic you should implement it yourself (or use some other string-parsing functions)

Also if I understand the logic of your parser correctly, I would suggest to use QChar for parameters fieldTerminator, lineTerminator, encloseChar -- these are expected to be one chars, not string, amirite?

Answer (score 0):

```
QChar strToChar(QString str)
{
    QChar ret;

    if(!str.isEmpty())
    {
        if(str.size() == 1)
            ret = str.at(0);
        else if(str.size() == 2 && str.startsWith('\\'))
        {
            // special char
            QChar tmp = str.at(1);
            if(tmp == '\'')
                ret = '\'';
            else if(tmp == '\"')
                ret = '\"';
            else if(tmp == '?')
                ret = '\?';
            else if(tmp == '\\')
                ret = '\\';
            else if(tmp == 'a')
                ret = '\a';
            else if(tmp == 'b')
                ret = '\b';
            else if(tmp == 'e')
                ret = '\e';
            else if(tmp == 'f')
                ret = '\f';
            else if(tmp == 'n')
                ret = '\n';
            else if(tmp == 'r')
                ret = '\r';
            else if(tmp == 't')
                ret = '\t';
            else if(tmp == 'v')
                ret = '\v';
        }
        // hex, oct, unicode missing
    }

    return ret;
}
```

That's what I'm using now... But I would like to see a nicer implementation